# Bridging two ethernet ports on seperate computers over WiFi

Tags: ethernet, wifi-transfer

Is it possible to take two Ethernet ports on two different laptops and use WiFi in order to link them together?

Comment: Unless you make this question more specific, I'm not sure what would be a better answer than just "yes, it's possible". It's not even clear whether this question is about IP traffic on the Windows operating system or something else entirely.

Comment: I agree with David. Are you using Windows and which version. Linux then which Distro. Do you want to link the two laptops together or are you trying to create a hot spot?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Laptop 1 is plugged in via ethernet and laptop 2 needs Wifi internet.. then you can create a WIFI Hotspot on your laptop using this method:
http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.